# type object 'RestrictionType' has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, biopython

I ran into this problem today, and wanted to bring it up to see if anyone else has seen it.  Searching Google/SO/Biostars didn't get me anywhere.

I'm running a simple restriction analysis (on a randomly generated "genome"), and getting this error. If I look for cut sites with the enzymes individually, it works for each. However, when I put them into a `RestrictionBatch`, I get an error on the class:

```
type object 'RestrictionType' has no attribute 'size'
```

I put up an [IPython notebook describing this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/cfriedline/7790932).

Versions:
- Biopython 1.6.2
- IPython 1.1.0
- Python 2.7.6/Anaconda 1.8

I've also tried this with Python 3.3 and the [latest pull](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/8be2402b8424722121d14c286b62bf70e8befde9) from the Biopython Git repository - same error.

Comment: I also experimented some problems with this format, maybe will change soon this module they are wanting to change it. ([here](http://lists.open-bio.org/pipermail/biopython-dev/2013-December/010991.html), and [here](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/268))

Answer (score 1):

This is something with iPython. Can be isolated with:

```
from Bio import Restriction as rst

rst.EcoRI
```

The last line crashes an IPython console with `AttributeError: type object 'RestrictionType' has no attribute 'size'`, while it runs just fine in the Python console. Oddly both:

```
rst.EcoRI.size
getattr(rst.EcoRI, "size")
```

gives the expected "6" in the IPython console.

---

Here is my workaround, generating the enzimes on the fly (on IPython):

```
from Bio.Restriction import Restriction as rst
from Bio.Restriction.Restriction_Dictionary import rest_dict, typedict

def create_enzyme(name):
    e_types = [x for t, (x, y) in typedict.items() if name in y][0]
    enzyme_types = tuple(getattr(rst, x) for x in e_types)
    return rst.RestrictionType(name, enzyme_types, rest_dict[name])

rb = create_enzyme("EcoRI") + create_enzyme("MstI")
# Or if you have a long list of restriction enzymes:
# enzyme_list = ["EcoRI", "MstI"]
# rb = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(create_enzyme, enzyme_list))

# Now it works

ana = rst.Analysis(rb, g, linear=True)
ana.with_sites()

Out[43]:

{__main__.EcoRI: [1440,
                  4108,
                  12547,
                  ...
```