# List and RestrictionType from Biopython

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key, biopython

I am experimenting some problems using the `Bio.Restrictions` methods, I am not sure if it is due to python, biopython or my poor understanding of python.

When I try to crate a `RestrictionBatch` following the [cookbook](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/cookbook/Restriction.html#mozTocId32850), I want to use enzymes I from a dictionary (read from files), and it says:

> You can initiate a restriction batch by passing it a list of enzymes
>   or enzymes name as argument.

In the python [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict.keys) for `dict.keys` says:

> Return a copy of the dictionary’s list of keys

So I tried this:

```
rb = RestrictionBatch(Enzymes.keys())
```

But I get an error: `ValueError: <type 'list'> is not a RestrictionType`

Testing where could be the error I created this code, to know if it is really a list or not

```
from Bio.Seq import Seq

Enzymes = {'XhoI': Seq('CTCGAG'), 'BsmBI': Seq('CGTCTC'), 'SceI': Seq('AGTTACGCTAGGGATAACAGGGTAATATAG'), 'BamHI': Seq('GGATCC'), 'BsaI': Seq('GGTCTC'), 'SacI': Seq('GAGCTC'), 'BbsI': Seq('GAAGAC'), 'AarI': Seq('CACCTGC'), 'EcoRI': Seq('GAATTC'), 'SpeI': Seq('ACTAGT'), 'CeuI': Seq('TTCGCTACCTTAGGACCGTTATAGTTACG')}

print Enzymes.keys() is list           #prints False
print isinstance(Enzymes.keys(), list) #prints True
print type(Enzymes.keys())             #prints <type 'list'>
```

Why this behaviour? And how can I use the dictionary to run the `RestrictionBatch`?

I am using:

```
Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 11 2012, 17:52:16) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)] on linux2

import Bio
print(Bio.__version__)
1.59
```

Minor question:
How can I check if it is or not in the database of Restriction? Is there any way to add one enzyme to this database (assuming I have the information needed)?

Comment: I don't think `is list` can be used to do type checking, in general. For instance, `[] is list` is False, even though an empty list is surely a list.

Comment: @Llopis, Some of the sequences that you have defined are already present in Bio.Restriction

Comment: Yes I know I found it later this package of biopython, in fact all of this enzymes are in `Biol.Restriction` but I have some other that are not in this version of biopython. I don't know if in the latest update from REBASE they are, but even if they aren't it would be nice to be able to include them without upgrading the version of biopython, (If they are included...)

Comment: You could try creating the Enzyme object by looking at it's components and then attaching them to Restriction module. You could do something as suggested in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354676/how-can-i-add-attributes-to-a-module-at-run-time

Answer (score 1):

The cookbook uses loosely the word "list". They talk about a list with the names of valid enzymes, that are already defined in the `import Bio.Restriction`. You can list all of them (along with other utilities) with:

```
from Bio import Restriction as rst

dir(rst)
```

But the RestrictionType is a bit more complex than a dict with names and seqs. This is the full definition for "EcoRI":

```
rest_dict["EcoRI"] = {
    'compsite' : '(?P<EcoRI>GAATTC)|(?P<EcoRI_as>GAATTC)',
    'results' : None,
    'site' : 'GAATTC',
    'substrat' : 'DNA',
    'fst3' : -1,
    'fst5' : 1,
    'freq' : 4096,
    'size' : 6,
    'opt_temp' : 37,
    'dna' : None,
    'inact_temp' : 65,
    'ovhg' : -4, 
    'scd3' : None,
    'suppl' : ('B', 'C', 'F', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'Q', 'R'
    'scd5' : None, 
    'charac' : (1, -1, None, None, 'GAATTC'),
    'ovhgseq' : 'AATT',
}
```

Plus a set with the suppliers, e.g.

```
suppliers["B"] = (
    'Invitrogen Corporation',
    ['MluI', 'HpaII', 'SalI', 'NcoI', 'ClaI', 'DraI', 'SstII', 'AvaI', ...)
```

And the typedict:

```
typedict["212"] = (
    ('NonPalindromic', 'OneCut', 'Ov5', 'Defined', 'Meth_Dep', ...),
    ['BssHII', 'BsrFI', 'DpnII', 'MluI', 'NgoMIV', 'HpaII', 'TspMI', ...],
)
```

These definitions are in `Bio.Restriction.Restriction_Dictionary`

Using the code I previously put in another [anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381912/type-object-restrictiontype-has-no-attribute-size/23907326#23907326):

```
from Bio.Restriction import Restriction as rst
from Bio.Restriction.Restriction_Dictionary import rest_dict, typedict

def create_enzyme(name):
    e_types = [x for t, (x, y) in typedict.items() if name in y][0]
    enzyme_types = tuple(getattr(rst, x) for x in e_types)

    return rst.RestrictionType(name, enzyme_types, rest_dict[name])

enzyme_list = ["EcoRI", "MstI"]
rb = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(create_enzyme, enzyme_list))
```

When the cookbook says "by passing it a list of enzymes or enzymes name", they are simplifying the things. As you can see in the source, `/Bio/Restriction/Restriction.py`, when the object RestrictionBatch is initialized, `__init__` calls `self.format`, and `self.format` checks that every item in the "list" is an instance of `RestrictionType`.

The minor answer for the minor question is:

```
>>> from Bio import Restriction as rst
>>> rst.hasattr(rst, "EcoRI")
True
>>> rst.hasattr(rst, "FakeEnzyme")
False
```

Or

```
>>> from Bio.Restriction.Restriction_Dictionary import rest_dict
>>> "EcoRI" in rest_dict.keys()
True
>>> "FakeEnzyme" in rest_dict.keys()
False
```